# Akka streams: Alpakka not using more than one CPU core

Tags: akka, cpu-usage, akka-stream, akka-cluster, alpakka

We have created a Alpakka stream, which consumes Kafka message from a topic and then process those messages. These messages are processed in parallel, using mapAsyncUnordered with a configured parallelism. The Kafka lag for the consumer increases, but the application uses only 1 core of CPU. I have changed the default dispatchers to akka.actor.default-dispatchers, which uses a fork-join executor expecting it to use more than a CPU core. I have my application running in 32 cores.
Please find the configured settings below:

```
akka.kafka.consumer.use-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
```

Consumer stream code:

```
Consumer.DrainingControl<Done> control = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topic))

                .buffer( 500, OverflowStrategy.backpressure() )

                //De-serialize the response from json to java object
                .mapAsyncUnordered( 5, //deserialize the output )

                .mapAsyncUnordered(5, //Process it and perform some calculations )

                .mapAsyncUnordered( 5, //Do something and return the consumer offset )

                //Commit the offset
                .toMat( Committer.sink(committerSettings.withMaxBatch(100)), Consumer::createDrainingControl)
                .run( materializer );
```

The stream runs in a akka-cluster, which is load balanced by same consumer group id. We have a typed actor system as well in the application which is used for triggering the request, with a group router which helps in sharing the load across the cluster. The triggered request is sent to a micro service as a Kafka message and we get a response as a Kafka message which is processed by streams. And these messages are not necessarily to be processed in order, hence the use of mapAsyncUnordered…

Tried increasing the parallelism to even 100, but didn’t see a change.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it is worth try to decrease the `.buffer( 500,...` to some value very low and check again if it uses more cores. I would add a log on each operator to make sure that the `Future` is passing the message on. The official doc says: `If a Future completes with null, element is not passed downstream`.

Comment: `mapAsyncUnordered(...)` will not by itself introduce any parallelism. It will just make sure that no more than `parallelism` futures/completionstages are pending completion at the same time. The actual source of parallelism must come from the functions passed to `mapAsyncUnordered`. Perhaps it's not the case and all processing happens on the same thread that the stream is executed on.

Comment: @Felipe, Thanks for the reply. I started with a lower buffer size. And there is no null value returned from any of the processing layer of stream. As we are committing the offset at the end, which should drill down till the last layer. Added a log as well as you suggested and it worked as expected, with a completed future object with offset and processed data.

Comment: The symptoms you describe seem most likely to be caused by creating already completed `CompletionStages` or blocking on completion.  Not knowing much about Java's futures and without the code in `mapAsyncUnordered`, I can't really help any more than counseling to look at how you're creating the futures.